# Display Special Characters in Drupal Forms API

Tags: forms

I have a variable fetch from database which contains special character `ñ`. For Example:

```
$student = 'Evangeline O. MontañO';
$student = 'Rosalyn G. QuiñO';
```

Displaying it in my form causes ajax error, but when I use `check_plain` function it returns an empty string and no ajax error occur. How can I display a variable with special characters on it without causing ajax error?

Comment: What type of element do you use in form?

Comment: @Eugene --> Just a simple div.

Comment: Please provide more info about how you add this into Drupal form

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` into `html.tpl.php` in your theme. This isn't an issue with Drupal, but your browser not recognising the UTF8 characters.

Comment: As a supplementary, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: Still doesnt work...

Comment: Can we see a demo?

Comment: Are you using the t() function, i.e. `$student = t('Evangeline O. MontañO');`

Comment: nope, my ajax callback function in my form wont work if I use t() function but when I use check_plain(),it works fine. The only caveat of check_plain is whenever the variable has special characters it returns an empty string. Making it not visible in my form. What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include more of your code?